# How to count with SQL grouped by cells in a grid?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, geometry

I use SQL and want to count the number of points in a grid of varying dimension.

I have found a solution bu I wonder if there might be a more elegant or efficient way to do this with the focus on Oracle.

This is my data basis:

```
create table tmpa (
  x number(10, 2),
  y number(10, 2),
  val number
);

insert into tmpa values (1.0, 1.8, 9);
insert into tmpa values (1.9, 2.0, 9);
insert into tmpa values (2.1, 1.9, 9);
insert into tmpa values (2.2, 2.6, 9);
insert into tmpa values (2.6, 2.7, 9);
insert into tmpa values (3.1, 3.9, 9);
insert into tmpa values (3.4, 3.7, 9);
insert into tmpa values (3.7, 3.8, 9);
```

Lets assume `x` and `y` are properly indexed.
This represents roughly points in a plane.

Now I want to count the number of points in cells of a grid. The grid starts at `(xmin,ymin)` and ends with `(xmax,ymax)` each divided into `cells` parts.

For an example could look like this:

```
  |       |       |       |
--+-------+-------+-------+-- 4.7
  |       |       |       |
  |       |    *  |       |
  |       |     * | *     |
--+-------+-------+-------+-- 3.5
  |       |       |       |
  |       |  *    |       |
  |     * |       |       |
--+-------+-------+-------+-- 2.3
  |       |       |       |
o |    ** |       |       |
  |       |       |       |
--+-------+-------+-------+-- 1.1
  |       |       |       |
 1.1     2.3     3.5     4.7
```

`cells` is `3` here, `xmin` and `ymin` is `1.1` and `xmax` and `ymax` is `4.7`, resulting in a cell-size (`dx` and `dy`) of `1.2`.

Now I want to count the number of points in each cell. As a convenience I could get the center point as a query result, too.

The result would look like this:

```
xcell ycell COUNT   center
  0,    0,    2,   1.65,1.65
  0,    1,    1,   1.65,2.85
  1,    1,    1,   2.85,2.85
  1,    2,    2,   2.85,4.05
  2,    2,    1    4.05,4.05
```

I would not mind to have the rows with a count zero listed as well.

This is exactly what the following query outputs:

```
-- 1.1: xmin, 4.7: xmax, cells:3, 1.2:(xmax-xmin)/cells ; same with y
Select d2.xcell, d2.ycell, d2.cnt, d2.xcell*1.2+1.1+1.1/2 xcenter, d2.ycell*1.2+1.1+1.1/2 ycenter
From (
  SELECT d1.xcell, d1.ycell, count(*) cnt
  FROM (
    select floor((x-1.1)/1.2) xcell, floor((y-1.1)/1.2) ycell
    from tmpa
  ) d1
  where d1.xcell>=1.1 and d1.xcell<4.7 and d1.ycell>=1.1 and d1.ycell<4.7
  group by xcell, ycell
) d2
Order By d2.xcell, d2.ycell
;
```

But this is more complicated that I thought it would be. And I don't know how efficient this is. Maybe there is a very efficient or very simple query that I just can not see.

Note: I do not want to use geo- or spatial extensions.

*Update:* I removed `between` because `>=` and `<` is better for half-open intervals.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause should be applied ***before*** you use `FLOOR()`, not after.  And it should be `>= 1.1 AND < 4.7` rather than `BETWEEN`.  Other than that, it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to your query but without some subqueries subqueries:

```
select xcell, ycell, cnt, xcell*1.2+1.1+1.1/2 as xcenter, ycell*1.2+1.1+1.1/2 ycenter
from (select floor((x-1.1)/1.2) as xcell, floor((y-1.1)/1.2) as ycell, count(*) as cnt
      from tmpa
      where xcell >= 1.1 and xcell < 4.7 and 
            ycell >= 1.1 and ycell < 4.7
      group by floor((x-1.1)/1.2), floor((y-1.1)/1.2)
     ) d
order By xcell, ycell;
```

This also fixed the bounds problem by replacing `between` with appropriate inequalities.

Comment: I contend that `BETWEEN` should not be used.  Based on the OP's description, 4.7 is in the 4th cell and the OP only wants 3 cells, therefore it should be using `>= 1.1 AND < 4.7`

Comment: @MatBailie . . . That seems logical to me but the OP is quite explicit that the given code works.

Comment: For the example data, sure, but even you (correctly) moved the WHERE clause to the correct place.  That the OP thinks their code works is simply a case of their test not correctly covering the boundary conditions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree with Mat here, my original code is wrong and only works for the example. Working with open intervals would be better.